# initWithNibName always loads English xib

Tags: iphone, localization, uiviewcontroller

I have a localized AboutApp.xib file with English and es localized versions, but it always loads the English version even when I have the phone's language set to Spanish.  How do I get it to load the Spanish version based on the language?

```
// Make sure AboutApp View is allocated
if (self.aboutAppController == nil) {
    AboutApp* aboutApp =
        [[AboutApp alloc] initWithNibName:@"AboutApp" bundle:nil];
    self.aboutAppController = aboutApp;
    [aboutApp release];
}

[UIView beginAnimations: nil context: nil];
[UIView setAnimationDuration: 1.0f];
[UIView setAnimationTransition: UIViewAnimationTransitionCurlUp
                       forView: [self.view window] cache: YES];
[self presentModalViewController: self.aboutAppController animated: YES];
[UIView commitAnimations];
```

Comment: I thought it might have something to do with the bundle parameter on the initWithNibName, but I don't understand how to set it even after reading the documentation.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

I found [the answer on macrumors](http://forums.macrumors.com/showthread.php?t=524415) forum.  Just needed to do a Build Clean and a rebuild for it to recognize the localization of the xib.